# How to display Android Cast button not in ActionBar

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

Is it possible to display the Chromecast Cast button not in the ActionBar. In particular, I am using CWAC Mediarouter and instead of displaying the Cast button in the ActionBar, I'd like to display it in the Drawer. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Thank You,
Gary Kipnis

Comment: Chromecast Cast button can be configurable. Refer [here] [1]. [1]:https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender

Answer (score 1):

`MediaRouteButton` is a `View` and, at least in theory, should work like any other `View`, like `Button`. If you are using the `mediarouter-v7` implementation, or my cross-port of it to avoid the `appcompat-v7` dependency, you would need to fully-qualify the class name in your layout file (e.g., `<com.commonsware.cwac.mediarouter.app.MediaRouteButton>`).

I personally have not used `MediaRouteButton` this way, so there may be issues that I'm not thinking of.

Comment: I wish it was true, got error like:
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100a3 a=2}
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1927)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
......
            at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:122)
will try this solution next:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547902/can-you-add-chromecast-functionality-without-using-the-actionbar